# What are spinor fields?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, tensors

For example, a tensor field $T=T_{a,b}^{\ \ \ \ c}$ on a manifold $M$ should be thought as 
$$
T_{a,b}^{\ \ \ \ c}dx^{a}\otimes dx^{b}\otimes \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{c}}
$$
with local coordinate $x=(x^{1},\dots,x^{n})$ of $M$. The transformation rule of tensors is nothing but the change of local coordinates of $M$, i.e. if one changes the local coordinate $x\mapsto y$ with Jacobian matrix $g$, then the tensor above transforms like 
$$
T_{a,b}^{\ \ \ \ c} \mapsto T_{A,B}^{\ \ \ \ C}=T_{a,b}^{\ \ \ \ c}g_{A}^{\ \ a}g^{\ \ b}_{B}g^{\ \ C}_{c}. 
$$
How should one think of the transformation rule of spinor fields? What local change reflects the transformation rule?

My question is a bit ambiguous, but I hope everyone can understand what I try to say. Thank you.

Comment: My understanding is that they transform like spin representations (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_representation) of orthogonal groups. But I don't think this explicit description in local coordinates is a good way to think about tensors and it's probably even less of a good way to think about spinors.

Comment: The proper answer to this question should address both Weyl and Majorana spinors as well as the methods to construct scalars from said quantities.

Comment: See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3961908/what-makes-spinors-mysterious/4110007#4110007).