# Is there a bundle concept that includes tensors and spinors as special cases?

Tags: tensors, vector-bundles, vector-fields, tangent-bundle, scalar-fields

A scalar field is a map from the base space to the field of interest but it is equivalently a section of a (0,0)-tensor bundle. Similarly, a vector bundle is just a section of a (1,0)-tensor bundle. In a similar way, Is there a larger bundle concept that includes tensors and spinors as special cases?

Comment: What is ypur definition of tensor and spinor? To me they are defined as section sone bundles.

Comment: Tensors and spinors are sections of some vector bundles. Is this what to you wanted to know?

Comment: @MoisheKohan No I want to know if there is a bundle concept where tensors and spinors are special cases. Similar to how a (0,0)-tensor is a scalar. I.e. I want some "(p,q)-bundle" where if p=0 it's a scalar bundle, if p=1/2 it's a spinor bundle, if p=1, it's a vector bundle, etc.

Comment: @ArcticChar I agree. Now I want a "(p,q)-bundle" where if p=0 it's a scalar bundle, if p=1/2 it's a spinor bundle, if p=1, it's a vector bundle, etc. Is there an extension of tensor and spinor bundles to a larger bundle type that includes these as special cases?

Comment: Then write your definition of a spinor bundle, because afaik, it is a special case of a vector bundle with some extra structure. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3961908/what-makes-spinors-mysterious/4110007#4110007).