# What's the name of the space that spinors and quaternions live in?

Tags: quaternions

I know the properties and most things about, but the Space they live I do not know the name, I find it strange not to have a name just hear that are kind of such a space, in some places until I heard that the space of spinors had the name of internal space, and I found nothing about, someone know the name?

Comment: I've heard "the space of quaternions"

Comment: @Ian, welcome to MSE. Maybe you want to read [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3961908/what-makes-spinors-mysterious) first. Here is a more accurate quote from Sir Michael Atiyah: "No one fully understands spinors. Their algebra is formally understood but their general significance is mysterious. In some sense they describe the 'square root' of geometry and, just as understanding the square root of -1 took centuries, the same might be true of spinors."

Comment: So your spaces don't really have a specific name?

Comment: I have a hard time parsing the question, but it seems there is a misunderstanding: The quaternions $\mathbb{H}$ *are* a space, they don't "live in" some larger space. The same is true of spinors, generally speaking, though the term "spinor" can refer to several different things.

Comment: the spinors they live in which space?

Comment: In the [fundamental representation of the Clifford algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinor#Mathematical_definition). In Kajelad's more rigorous language: they don't 'live' there. They *are* that space.